# Add Edge computing server between the clients and server

Tags: sockets, edges, federated-learning

I am trying to add a Edge Computing layar between Clients and server in flwr. I realized there is a problem here afterwhile. The first messages communicate properly but the FL procedure not started and stucks.

My edge code:

```
edge_server = EdgeServer(("0.0.0.0", 8081), EdgeHandler)
edge_server.serve_forever()
```

My client code:

```
fl.client.start_numpy_client(
server_address="127.0.0.1:8081",
client=FlowerClient(),
)
```

My server:

```
strategy = fl.server.strategy.FedAvg(evaluate_metrics_aggregation_fn=weighted_average,min_available_clients=2)

fl.server.start_server(
server_address="0.0.0.0:8080",
config=fl.server.ServerConfig(num_rounds=1),
strategy=strategy,
)
```